# How can django channels communicate to other microservices?

Tags: django, python-3.x, microservices, amqp

We are developing microservices and communicating between them over rabbitmq.

We would like to add a django app to the mix and currently are looking for elegant solutions.

I have taken a look at django [channels](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/routing.html). While they are able to communicate over rabbitmq, I haven't found mentioning on how to send messages to specific exchange (and preferably with specific routing key as we are mostly using topic exchanges).

[asgi-rabbitmq](https://asgi-rabbitmq.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) seems to be the one translating between asgi (protocol used by channels) and amqp (protocol used by rabbitmq). From the docs, however, I only understood how to enable it - not how to actually use it to publish messages.

Have I missed something?